Additive function and $|f(x)|\geq M$. Is the function linear
I have the following problem.
Let the function $f:R\to R$ will be additive and there is an open interval $[a,+ \infty), a>0$ and there is a number $M>0$, such that for each $x\in [a,+ \infty):|f(x)|≥M$. Show that f is linear?
I once received an answer to a similar problem and it seems to me that it could be useful.
The additive function bounded from below is linear, New question
In my opinion, it is enough to take and use the infinite sum of closed intervals to obtain the interval $[a,+ \infty)$ and consider two cases that $f(x)≥M$ and $f(x)≤−M$ (in both cases, as in the proof, argue for linearity).
Maybe it can be argued in a simpler way or shown differently? I would appreciate some fragment of the proof or some hints or argumentation. I would be grateful for any help.
Maybe there is such proof in some book, but unfortunately I did not find it, and I searched many items
Motivation.
Motivation is to find an answer and explanation of the issue that is not directly explained in books (maybe I did not find it). This is a very useful fact for me

This question is similar to: Cauchy's functional equation without the assumption of continuity. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for your attention, I have already corrected the typo

The question linked by @geetha290krm has slightly weaker assumption than yours, it's a duplicate.

In fact, how is this question different from the other question of yours that you yourself link...?
